# Support of Windows Store in Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Any plans on supporting Windows Store in Unity Facebook SDK?

We just tried to build our game for Windows Store, and the build breaks at just three places in IFacebook.dll, due to .NET Core library being used for Windows Store instead of full .NET. Would be really interesting to see if SDK would just work for Windows, should be a very easy fix to implement.

Here are the places where the build currently breaks:

1) Reference Rewriter: Error: method `System.String System.String::Copy(System.String)` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from IFacebook.dll at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.String> Facebook.AbstractFacebook::CopyByValue(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2).

2) Reference Rewriter: Error: method `System.Reflection.Assembly System.Type::get_Assembly()` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from IFacebook.dll at Facebook.FBBuildVersionAttribute[] Facebook.FBBuildVersionAttribute::getAttributes(System.Type).

3) Reference Rewriter: Error: method `System.Object[] System.Reflection.Assembly::GetCustomAttributes(System.Type,System.Boolean)` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from IFacebook.dll at Facebook.FBBuildVersionAttribute[] Facebook.FBBuildVersionAttribute::getAttributes(System.Type).

Missing methods are quite easy to implement as extensions...

Answer (score -1):

For the time being, I had to remove the Facebook SDK so I could compile for Windows Store Universal.

It would be nice if Facebook could fix this.